# AngularJS - Chamar directive ao remodelar página

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Tenho uma directive que determina o tamanho e largura de alguns elementos, mas quando mudo a dimensão da página ele não se adapta.
Gostaria de um modo de que quando o usuário alterar as dimensões do seu navegador o angular chame novamente a directive.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o $watch, como neste exemplo:

```
 app.directive('myDirective', ['$window', function ($window) {

     return {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>window size: {{width}}px</div>'
     };

     function link(scope, element, attrs){

       scope.width = $window.innerWidth;

       angular.element($window).bind('resize', function(){

         scope.width = $window.innerWidth;

         // manuall $digest required as resize event
         // is outside of angular
         scope.$digest();
       });

     }
 }]);
```

Exemplo citado https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622673/angularjs-watch-window-resize-inside-directive

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou, tentei deste modo e outros parecidos e ainda continua a não atualizar a directive.